# Two way internet sharing configuration (swiching modem from one machine to another)

Tags: networking

I have:

1. One Raspberry Pi with Raspbian (distribution based on Debian), with one enthernet interface
2. One laptop with windows, with one ethernet interface
3. One USB modem
4. Ethernet cable between Pi and laptop

I want to:

1. Share internet on Raspberry Pi when modem is connected to Pi
2. Use internet which is shared on laptop when modem is connected to laptop.

What I have done:

1. My modem is working on both machines, its ppp0 interface on Pi. ppp0 has dynamic IP.
2. Sharing internet from laptop to Raspberry works. Laptop IP: 192.168.137.1

Question:

**How can I share internet on Raspberry Pi without ruining too much / reconfiguring network on both machines when I switch modem from one machine to another?**

Extra question: I know that interfaces on both windows and linux can have multiple IP addresses. Can I have both configurations set and just plug my modem here and there and start connection to have internet on second machine?